# pandas DataFrame combine_first and update methods have strange behavior

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I'm running into a strange issue (or intended?) where `combine_first` or `update` are causing values stored as `bool` to be upcasted into `float64`s if the argument supplied is not supplying the boolean columns.

Example workflow in ipython:

```
In [144]: test = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,False,True],[4,5,True,False]], columns=['a','b','isBool', 'isBool2'])

In [145]: test
Out[145]:
   a  b isBool isBool2
0  1  2  False    True
1  4  5   True   False


In [147]: b = pd.DataFrame([[45,45]], index=[0], columns=['a','b'])

In [148]: b
Out[148]:
    a   b
0  45  45

In [149]: test.update(b)

In [150]: test
Out[150]:
    a   b  isBool  isBool2
0  45  45       0        1
1   4   5       1        0
```

Was this meant to be the behavior of the `update` function? I would think that if nothing was specified that `update` wouldn't mess with the other columns.

---

**EDIT**: I started tinkering around a little more. The plot thickens. If I insert one more command: `test.update([])` before running `test.update(b)`, boolean behavior works at the cost of numbers upcasted as `objects`. This also applies to DSM's simplified example.

Based on [panda's source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L3830), it looks like the reindex_like method is creating a DataFrame of dtype `object`, while reindex_like `b` creates a DataFrame of dtype `float64`. Since `object` is more general, subsequent operations work with bools. Unfortunately running `np.log` on the numerical columns will fail with an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Simpler example: `df = pd.DataFrame([True, False]); df.update({})`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a bug, update shouldn't touch unspecified columns, fixed here https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3021

Comment: Hopefully it gets merged back into master. Thanks!

Comment: this has been merged in give a try

Comment: Looks good I think - however, I see this unintended behavior in other functions as well. I see it in methods `combine_first`, and `groupby.first/last`.

Comment: groupby is complicated to fix, will have a look at combine_first

Answer (score 3):

Before updating, the dateframe `b` is been filled by [reindex_link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html), so that b becomes

```
In [5]: b.reindex_like(a)
Out[5]: 
    a   b  isBool  isBool2
0  45  45     NaN      NaN
1 NaN NaN     NaN      NaN
```

And then use [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to update the data frame.

The tragedy is that for `numpy.where`, if two data have different type, the more general one would be used. For example

```
In [20]: np.where(True, [True], [0])
Out[20]: array([1])

In [21]: np.where(True, [True], [1.0])
Out[21]: array([ 1.])
```

Since `NaN` in `numpy` is floating type, it'll also return an floating type.

```
In [22]: np.where(True, [True], [np.nan])
Out[22]: array([ 1.])
```

Therefore, after updating, your 'isBool' and 'isBool2' column become floating type.

I've added this issue on [the issue tracker for pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3016)

Comment: Makes sense - I think there simply isn't a guard to prevent unexpected edits of other columns