# dtype lost in pandas combine_first

Tags: python, join, pandas, concatenation, series

I encountered a strange behavior when using combine_first for two Series (pandas version 0.14.1).
s1 and s2 are both of type int32. The resulting Series is of type float. This doesn't happen when using e.g. concat. I wonder, did I misunderstand something or stumble across a bug?

I have read this thread, but it seems to be something else:
[pandas DataFrame combine_first and update methods have strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349795/pandas-dataframe-combine-first-and-update-methods-have-strange-behavior)

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series

s1 = Series(range(0, 5), index=pd.date_range('20140903', periods=5, freq='d'))
s2 = Series(range(0, 5), index=pd.date_range('20140901', periods=5, freq='d'))

print s1.combine_first(s2)
```

Comment: I think the second answer is what is really happening, because your indices are not identical you have gaps so these look they are being converted to float64 to handle this inconsitency, for instance if both your series had the same indices then the dtype is preserved. I can't say if this is a bug or not but it seems intended

Comment: Thanks, this sounds reasonable. I guess I'll have to add an .astype(int) then to circumvent this behaviour.

Comment: There are multiple tickets for this issue on the pandas GitHub tracker, e.g. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7509