# pandas DataFrame combine_first method converts boolean in floats

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm running into a strange issue where combine_first method is causing values stored as bool to be upcasted into float64s.
Example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [True]})

In [3]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({"b": ['test']})

In [4]: df2.combine_first(df1)
Out[4]:
     a     b
0  1.0  test
```

This problem has already been reported in a previous post 3 years ago: [pandas DataFrame combine_first and update methods have strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15349795/3894837). This issue was told to be solved but I still have this behaviour under pandas 0.18.1

thank you for your help

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am wondering why the method combine_first does not keep the bool values in column 'a'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere along the chain of events to get to a combined dataframe, potential missing values had to be addressed.  I'm aware that nothing is missing in your example.  `None` and `np.nan` are not `int`, or `bool`.  So in order to have a common `dtype` that contains a `bool` and a `None` or `np.nan` it is necessary to cast the column as either `object` or `float`.  As 'float`, a large number of operations become far more efficient and is a decent choice.  It obviously isn't the best choice all of the time, but a choice has to be made none the less and pandas tried to infer the best one.

A work around:

***Setup***

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [True]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"b": ['test']})

df3 = df2.combine_first(df1)
df3
```

[image]

***Solution***

```
dtypes = df1.dtypes.combine_first(df2.dtypes)

for k, v in dtypes.iteritems():
    df3[k] = df3[k].astype(v)

df3
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. This specific case does not seem to be fixed in Pandas yet. I've filed a bug report:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20699

Comment: @Stephen Rauch: I had added the comment you deleted because I've seen answers getting down-voted for not being answers to the question. Strictly speaking I'm not answering the question. I'm just trying to help others as I ran into the same issue as the poster and others may also.

Comment: I am quite aware of why the text was there. However, I had one of two choices.  Vote to delete this answer because it was not an answer.  Or turn it into an answer by removing a bunch of text that was *completely irrelevant* to the answer.